# Docker-compose file of Airflow with DaskExecutor

Tags: airflow, dask, ray

Can someone provide a YAML file of the same mentioned above? I need it for a project.

I am trying to execute my tasks parallelly on each core of the workers, as it provides a performance boost for the task.
To achieve this I want to execute my Airflow tasks directly on the Dask cluster. As my project requires Airflow to be run on docker, I couldn't find any `docker-compose.yaml` file for Airflow with DaskExecutor.
Dask generally has a scheduler and some workers in its cluster.

Apart from this, I've tried to achieve this task parallelism with the airflow-provider-ray library by Astronomer registry. I've used [this](https://registry.astronomer.io/dags/task-flow-ray-pandas-example-demo) documentation to achieve so in docker. But I am facing OSError: Connection timeout. Here I am running airflow in docker and ray cluster on my local python environment.

Secondly, I've tried the same with the dask cluster. In this, there is Airflow running on docker with celery executor, and in another docker, there is Dask scheduler, two workers, and a notebook. Then I am able to connect these but I keep getting error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unusual_prefix_2774d32fcb40c2ba2f509980b973518ede2ad0c3_dask_client'`.

The solution to any of these problems will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited my question with more details. Please let me know if someone wants to see my docker-compose files for Airflow and Dask cluster. The connection established between those two dockers is by a network string
 """
networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: dask_network